# Mocha test not running Chai assertion using Meteor

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, mocha.js, chai

For my project, I am trying to set up Mocha to run Chai tests, but am having an issue where the tests are simply not running at all. The browser reports that no tests are passing, failing, or running.

Here is the code for the tests:

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';

if (Meteor.isclient) {

    describe('Recipe model', function () {
        it('should test that a recipe is created', function () {
            assert.isTrue(true);
        });
    });
}
```

I run the test using the following command:

```
    meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha
```

I have installed practicalmeteor:chai as well. A google search suggested putting chai.should() at the beginning of my test, but that did not help. I am open to all suggestions.

Cheers!

Comment: Is the test file loaded at all? Where did you place the file? Have you consulted The Meteor Guide?

Comment: I have consulted the Meteor Guide a good number of times. As far as I can tell, to run the test, you just run the line I posted originally and make sure that all your test files are *.test.js. The location of the files shouldn't matter, but in the event that it does, my tests are under root > client > tests.

Comment: Did you get your client tests running @Shyyk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had weird issues with importing assert. I just had to do the following as noted from @Tdm:

```
import {chai} from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai'
```

Comment: This should rather be marked as the answer to the question. Putting it as a comment doesn't necessarily indicate that the question has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible issues is typo at 4th line of your code: replace `Meteor.isclient`  with `Meteor.isClient`. Your test even didn't executed because `Meteor.isclient` was always `false`.

Comment: You're right! I changed this to be the correct code, but it still did not run the test. Also, I can take the conditional out and the test still doesn't run...

Comment: I don't see any other issues except chai import (probably it should be `import { assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';`). Also, I recommend you to check out [Meteor Todos](https://github.com/meteor/todos) project. It contains examples of test and everything is correctly configured.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not put your test file inside /tests directory. I know its not intuitive but meteor ignores everything inside /tests.

Comment: I ran into this issue, fixed it by renaming "tests" to "test" ( `mv tests/ test/` ).